# To import world cities to database or not?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to have countries and cities dropdowns to my site. I've found this huge list (~3million) of cities http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities and I wonder if it is proper to import this to my database or it will become too heavy. 
How to handle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A drop-down with 3 million entries might be a tad too heavy, yes. :) Seriously though - how do you want  to do it? UI-wise? The database won't care if it has a table with 3 million entries in it, but the real question is how you want to query the data in it.

Comment: there will be 2 drop downs 1 for countries and when country is selected it will populate the city drop down via ajax

Comment: @chchrist There are less than 200 countries in the world, you still need to filter the cities for countries like the US where there will still be thousands of cities.

Comment: Hmmm you're right. I have to either narrow them down using state names or make an autocomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy with the "open data license" clauses there is nothing to stop you using the list - but I think you will need to use something more intuitive than a plain dropdown for 3 million items; some kind of ajaxy autocomplete seems more appropriate.

Three million rows is nothing mysql can't handle - depends on whether the storage is worth the data.  Perhaps you could strip out cities that are irrelevent?

> All advertising materials and documentation mentioning features or use
>   of this database must display the following acknowledgment: "This
>   product includes data created by MaxMind, available from
>   http://www.maxmind.com/"
>
> Redistribution and use with or without modification, are permitted
>   provided that the following conditions are met:
>   1. Redistributions must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or
>   other materials provided with the distribution. 
>   2. All advertising materials and documentation mentioning features or use of this database must display the following acknowledgement: "This
>   product includes data created by MaxMind, available from
>   http://www.maxmind.com/"
>   3. "MaxMind" may not be used to endorse or promote products derived from this database without specific prior written permission.

Comment: It is a site where you add your holiday home for advertisement. I'll use ajax drop downs.I will provide reference to those guys

Answer (score 1):

Perform horizontal list partitioning by Continent.

Comment: 3 million cities, 5 continents, still 600k cities per continent on average....  some dropdown that will be.

Comment: I only gave an answer on his question (increasing performance, by splitting the db over multiple nodes). In his GUI he should filter on Continent > Country > "Text-Input with autocomplete"

Comment: the increased complexity introduced by partitioning is probably overkill for "just" 3M compact records with well defined (indexed) access ...